# convert stringbuilder to guid

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Hi I've some guids in stringbuilder and I want to store these values in guid array.

Can some one give me idea to convert this. I'm working with vb.net

Thanks in advance

Comment: Well, "How did *you* get them in there?" Because, getting them out should be the exact opposite process ..

Comment: fetching from database. Is there any method like Dim empids As Guid() foreach (empid in employee) empids.add(empid)

Comment: Okay, well, *How* is/are the GUID(s) stored in a String? (Providing sample data might help clarify some things.)

Answer (score 0):

Assumption: your guids are really simply strings.
Than that might help:

```
Dim SB as new Stringbuilder = "GUID"
Dim GuidList as New List(Of Guid)

Dim myGUID as Guid
If GUID.tryparse(SB.tostring, myGuid)=true then
   Guidlist.add(myguid)
else
  'Handle the error here
end if
```

Wrap this in a loop over your Guids, I don't know how you stored them.
Remarks: You might need to use parsexact, see the documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid.aspx
I have written out of my head, so the code might not compile...

Comment: Does that first line even compile?  How can you assign a string literal to an instance of StringBuilder?

Comment: Without Vb.net at hand, I do not remember the syntax exactly. but it is possible to instantiate a Strinbuilder with a string. Even if not, simply create the SB first and then call append with the Literal... I intended this as an idea guide, nocht "ready to compile" solution.